# Why am I getting such bad render glitches using custom paint on Android?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implements Rings that are similar to the Apple Watch rings. I'm drawing these rings as arcs using Canvas and a CustomPaint widget.

```
canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCircle(
      center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), radius: radius - 10),
  -pi / 2,
  completion,
  false,
  Paint()
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 20
    ..color = color
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round,
```

The rings look like this:
[image]

I have a stateful widget that I'm using to increment the rings. This works perfectly fine.

However, I also have a background to the rings that is also drawn using Canvas which consists of arcs, circles, shadows and custom paths. I'm
using a Stack widget to put one on top of the other:

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
      RingsBackground(),
      CustomPaint(
        size: Size(300, 300),
        painter: CirclePainter(streak: streak),
      ),
    ])
```

When I do this and increment and complete some of the circles, I'm getting really bad rendering glitches but only on Android and not on iOS. Interestingly if I close my app on android and reopen it (or switch to another app and switch back) it works fine. This is what the glitch looks like.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this or create a workaround? Have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

So I found out that this only happens while using canvas to paint outside the width and heigh that you provide in the CustomPaint widget. Once I restructured everything to fit within those bounds, everything worked fine.